# UIButton not triggering action if place between two views

Tags: ios, button, uigesturerecognizer

I've got a UIButton which is linked to a correspondent @IBAction. Such button is located exactly in the middle of two adjacent views

`|--------------|----------------|
| view1    | button |  view2    |
|--------------|----------------|`

The UIButton is a subview of view1 (important!), but is located in the middle using a frame with a negative value for the 'x' position.

Both views have a UITapGestureRecognizer, used to trigger some stuff.

The problem is the following: if I tap on the left side of the button (the one over view1) the IBAction is triggered, while if I tap on the right part of the button (the one on view2) the IBAction is not triggered, while the UIGestureRecognizer on view2 is.

I know that this is probably because the button belongs to view1 and not view2, but is there a way to detect this?

I tried with the suggested approach

```
override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
   /*detect if you tapped button or view*/
}
```

which is correctly invoked, but always saying that the view tapped is view2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go with two buttons and make them appear like one, each one on view1 and view2 held closer. If you have a title on the button, then have a label behind the button with the same frame as your current button on view1 and make the two button's background color as clearcolor. Keep the same target and selector for both buttons. Simple and Easy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your storyboard the button is above the views, see the attached screenshot, where the Button is above the textField.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your button is likely being covered by one of your other views, so those views are swallowing the taps. I suggest running your app and using the debug menu's view debugging option to see the hierarchy of views. I'm not at my Mac right now so I can't give you the specific command, but there is a menu option that pauses your running app and shows a 3d representation of your back-to-front view hierarchy. It's invaluable in figuring out stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is a subview of view1, taps outside of view1's bounds won't register. That's why you can tap on the left side, but not the right.

It would be better to to make view1, view2 and the button children of the same superview, and make sure the button is added on top of the two views.

Comment: Thanks, it was my idea too. The problem is that view1 and view1 are actually cells of a scrollview :(